# using goMap jQuery plugin for google maps api, how can i modify map to allow markers to be added on click?

Tags: jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have been pretty pleased so far with this plugin, but am having a little issue getting to let me use $goMap.setMap() to allow addMarker.

once the map has been created, i am trying the following: (default is addMarker: false)

```
$.goMap.setMap({ addMarker: true });
```

what i am trying to accomplish is to only allow the user to add markers from high zoom levels to they can be more accurate. i can track the zoom level easy enough and i can modify other controls such as nav type and position, but can't set addMarker to true (or multi or false).

it's a great plugin but seems to lack much documentation, although there are a ton of examples.

plugin url:
http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/examples.php

any ideas on this would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*i can track... but can't set addMarker to true (or multi or false).*"

I can't understand the question, but I suggest to use directly the google maps API, I don't see this plugin very useful.